# How do i determine the middle time of two times?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i thought of doing it this way:

```
middle_time = (time + time[1]) / 2
```

is this the accurate way or is there a better way to do it? How can i determine the middle time between two times?

Answer (score 1):

If by middle you meant average, then this is the proper way to do it.

You could also use the `math.avg` function ([documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Davg)).

```
middle_time = math.avg(time, time[1])
```

Comment: [What is a better way to achieve this?](https://postimg.cc/hzw7Kz3D)

Answer (score 1):

Two considerations:

1. It really depends of your definition of "middle time". Are you consider time to be continuous or discrete? If it is continuous, what you are doing is ok, if it is discrete you would need to round it depending on the size of your "time bins".
2. If you want your code to be more clear, you can calculate it differently, by finding the time difference, dividing it by two and adding it to the first time. If you simplify the formula it is the same thing, but if you write it this way the intention is more clear.

Comment: [This is what i am trying to achieve](https://postimg.cc/hzw7Kz3D). [This is the code i have as of now](https://postimg.cc/c60J8cwp). this code doesn't result in what i need.

Comment: Well, you only mentioned that you are trying to find the "middle time", not that you are trying to *plot* something on the midpoint of a line. You should edit your question and provide information about your actual problem, your current output, how it differs from the wanted output and also paste your code, along with any libraries you are using. I can't guess how this code does not do the job if you don't show us *what* it does.